# SAPUI5: After disabling the Rich Text Edior, still able to paste the content from word/web

Tags: javascript, sapui5, tinymce-4

I am using [RichTextEditor](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.richtexteditor.RichTextEditor/controlProperties) control from SAPUI5. There is a property 'editable'. I have set it false so that user can't enter the text. But still it is allowing content to paste on Editor. Ideally, this should not happen. Please find below info about editable property:

> editable      boolean   true
>   Determines whether the editor content can be modified by the user. When set to "false" there might not be any editor toolbar.

Visibility: public

Can anybody help in disabling pasting content also ??

Any lead or help will be appreciated. Thanks.

> Here is the link of my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pranavk_19/9yz4hkam/)

```js
sap.ui.controller("myController", {
    onInit: function () {
},
    
});
sap.ui.view({
    viewContent: jQuery('#myXml').html(),
    type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
}).placeAt("content")
```

```html
<script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.viz" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
    
</script>
<script id="myXml" type="text/xmldata">
    <mvc:View xmlns:core = "sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:mvc = "sap.ui.core.mvc" 
    xmlns = "sap.m" xmlns:richtexteditor="sap.ui.richtexteditor"
    controllerName = "myController"
    displayBlock = "true"> <App> <Page title = "Hello"> 
    
    <richtexteditor:RichTextEditor
   id="idrichtexteditor1" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop sapUiSmallMarginBegin mceContentBody"
   editable="false" editorType="TinyMCE4" beforeEditorInit="onBeforeInit" ready="onReady" useLegacyTheme="false" showGroupClipboard="false" showGroupTextAlign="true" showGroupStructure="true" showGroupLink="true"  showGroupFont="false"
change="onChange" keyDown ="onKeyPress">
   </richtexteditor:RichTextEditor>
    
    </Page>
   </App> </mvc:View>
</script>
<body class='sapUiBody'>
    <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the `powerpaste` plugin: `myRichTextEditor.removePlugin("powerpaste");`

To add the plugin again: `myRichTextEditor.addPlugin("powerpaste");`

You can see it working in the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yz4hkam/5/)